# Errors while installing modules using Pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm facing this issue when I was trying to install matplotlib library using pip.
Then I found out that this error still **occurs even when I try to install other libraries**.

My python installation path -
`C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe`

I did this - `PS C:\Users\mihir> pip install matplotlib`
Using the admin mode inside Windows Terminal. Still shows the same when I run in CMD prompt in admin mode.

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 104, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand, with_cleanup
  File "C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.collector import LinkCollector
  File "C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests
  File "C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .html5parser import HTMLParser, parse, parseFragment
  File "C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\html5parser.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import _inputstream
  File "C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_inputstream.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import webencodings
ImportError: cannot import name 'webencodings' from 'pip._vendor' (C:\Users\mihir\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\__init__.py)```<br>
````

Comment: Can you try `python -c "import ssl"` and see what happens? Reference: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the whole Python Interpreter helped me!

Answer (score 0):

You must have inadvertently upgraded your system pip (probably through something like `pip install pip --upgrade`)

If so, you will need to reinstall pip:

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: Actually, whenever I tried installing anyother module, same error occured.